# Why is the kerning of italic "Ex-Vivo" messed up?

Tags: italic, kerning

When typesetting "Ex-Vivo" in italic, there is large apparent spacing between the dash and the V. Does this mean that my LaTeX setup is misconfigured, or am I expected to set the kerning manually for this case?

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{Ex-Vivo}

\section{\textit{Ex-Vivo}}

Ex-Vivo

\textit{Ex-Vivo}

\end{document}
```

Comment: IMHO this is a kerning issue of the `-V` pair or the font. Already the kerning of the first example is not really good. You can improve it using `Ex-\kern-.12em Vivo` resp. `\textit{Ex-\kern-.2em Vivo}`.

Comment: If you are open to using other fonts, you can avoid the problem. For example with charter: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Hcoz.png

Comment: With [`libertinus`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertinus) the kerning is also correct without manual correction.

Comment: Thank you all for helping!